# Add Character and Space in a string using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have one Recursive function in which Input is a string and in output, we are getting Double Character with Space. What is the logic of this?

```
def recursive(string):
     ...
     ...
```

> Input  :  "Hello"
>
> Output :  "HH ee ll ll oo"

Comment: Without seeing the code for the recursive function, how can anyone possibly make a comment here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have code. I want the solution to this problem.

Comment: looks like school work. you should at least show pseudo code or your failed attempt to show your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def recursive(string):
  if not string:
    return ''
  else:
    c = string[0]
    rest = string[1:]
    return c + c + ' ' + recursive(rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could also handle this using a single line of regex:

```py
inp = "Hello"
output = re.sub(r'(.)', r'\1\1 ', inp)
print(output)  # HH ee ll ll oo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
>>> t = 'Hello'
           
>>> ' '.join('{0}{0}'.format(t[i]) for i in range(len(t)))
           
'HH ee ll ll oo'
```